# Pandas: How to insert dataframe into Clickhouse

Tags: python, pandas, clickhouse

I am trying to insert a Pandas dataframe into Clickhouse.

This is my code

```
import pandas
import sqlalchemy as sa

uri = 'clickhouse://default:@localhost/default'
ch_db = sa.create_engine(uri)

pdf = pandas.DataFrame.from_records([
    {'year': 1994, 'first_name': 'Vova'},
    {'year': 1995, 'first_name': 'Anja'},
    {'year': 1996, 'first_name': 'Vasja'},
    {'year': 1997, 'first_name': 'Petja'},
])

pdf.to_sql('test_humans', ch_db, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

And this is the error that I am receiving. Does this have to do with some missing extra arguments regarding the ENGINE? How can I fix this?

> Exception: Code: 62, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Syntax error:
>   failed at position 65 (line 7, col 2): FORMAT
>   TabSeparatedWithNamesAndTypes. Expected one of: ENGINE, storage
>   definition (version 19.15.2.2 (official build))

Logging

> INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:EXISTS TABLE test_humans
>   INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
>   INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine: CREATE TABLE test_humans (
>           first_name TEXT,
>           year BIGINT )
>
> INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
>   INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:ROLLBACK

Comment: Are you using [clickhouse](https://github.com/cloudflare/sqlalchemy-clickhouse)-dialect for sqlalchemy? Could you provide the schema description for *test_humans*-table?

Comment: Yes I am. When using to_sql(), pandas will usually create a schema automatically. I guess it has to do with exactly that. The create schema sql statement that the dialect is creating misses some proprietary command regarding "ENGINE".

Comment: See my update.. some log information about the issued queries.

Comment: which driver you use exacly https://github.com/mymarilyn/clickhouse-driver or  https://github.com/cloudflare/sqlalchemy-clickhouse ?

Answer (score 6):

Starting with version 0.2.0 clickhouse_driver implements method `insert_dataframe`. See: https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#clickhouse_driver.Client.insert_dataframe

Comment: This works very well. It is very easy, and is more efficient than using `client.execute("INSERT INTO your_table VALUES", df.to_dict('records'))` because it will transpose the DataFrame and send the data in columnar format.

This doesn't do automatic table generation, but I wouldn't trust that anyway. Clickhouse has too many important decisions of schema design - especially partitioning - to leave this to autogen.

Comment: Somehow I needed use_numpy=True.  `Client('localhost', settings={"use_numpy":True})` else

Comment: Would be helpful to include the actual example of usage as it is missing from official documentation: 
`client.insert_dataframe('INSERT INTO your_table VALUES', df)`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without `sqlalchemy`.

> pip install clickhouse-driver

```
from clickhouse_driver import Client


client = Client('localhost')
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records([
    {'year': 1994, 'first_name': 'Vova'},
    {'year': 1995, 'first_name': 'Anja'},
    {'year': 1996, 'first_name': 'Vasja'},
    {'year': 1997, 'first_name': 'Petja'},
])

client.insert_dataframe(
    'INSERT INTO "your_table" (year, first_name) VALUES',
    df,
    settings=dict(use_numpy=True),
)

# or 
client.execute("INSERT INTO your_table VALUES", df.to_dict('records'))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use https://github.com/kszucs/pandahouse to insert your dataframe without extra conversions.

> pip install pandahouse

```
import pandahouse as ph

pdf = pandas.DataFrame.from_records([
    {'year': 1994, 'first_name': 'Vova'},
    {'year': 1995, 'first_name': 'Anja'},
    {'year': 1996, 'first_name': 'Vasja'},
    {'year': 1997, 'first_name': 'Petja'},
])

connection = dict(database='default',
                  host='localhost',
                  user='default',
                  password='')

ph.to_clickhouse(pdf, 'test_humans', index=False, chunksize=100000, connection=connection)
```

Answer (score 1):

[sqlalchemy-clickhouse](https://github.com/cloudflare/sqlalchemy-clickhouse) cannot create table automatically (at least until version *0.1.5.post0* inclusively) and interprets any sql-query of table creation as *SELECT*-query that always tail by *FORMAT TabSeparatedWithNamesAndTypes*-clause.

To work around this issue need to create a table manually using the [infi.clickhouse_orm](https://github.com/Infinidat/infi.clickhouse_orm)-api (this module delivered with *sqlalchemy-clickhouse*):

```py
import pandas as pd
from infi.clickhouse_orm.engines import Memory
from infi.clickhouse_orm.fields import UInt16Field, StringField
from infi.clickhouse_orm.models import Model
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


# define the ClickHouse table schema
class Test_Humans(Model):
    year = UInt16Field()
    first_name = StringField()
    engine = Memory()


engine = create_engine('clickhouse://default:@localhost/test')

# create table manually
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.connection.create_table(Test_Humans) # https://github.com/Infinidat/infi.clickhouse_orm/blob/master/src/infi/clickhouse_orm/database.py#L142

pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
    {'year': 1994, 'first_name': 'Vova'},
    {'year': 1995, 'first_name': 'Anja'},
    {'year': 1996, 'first_name': 'Vasja'},
    {'year': 1997, 'first_name': 'Petja'},
    # ! sqlalchemy-clickhouse ignores the last item so add fake one
    {}
])

pdf.to_sql('test_humans', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Take into account that *sqlalchemy-clickhouse* ignores the last item so add fake one (see [source code](https://github.com/cloudflare/sqlalchemy-clickhouse/blob/v0.1.5/connector.py#L238) and related [issue 10](https://github.com/cloudflare/sqlalchemy-clickhouse/issues/10)).

Let's check this table in DB:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM test.test_humans

┌─year─┬─first_name─┐
│ 1994 │ Vova       │
│ 1995 │ Anja       │
│ 1996 │ Vasja      │
│ 1997 │ Petja      │
└──────┴────────────┘

4 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.003 sec.
*/
```

---

See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68843676/303298 too.