# How to insert a DF into a clickhouse table, if data type is uuid and list of datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert, clickhouse

I have a df as a result of a sql query, rows are as follows:

```
UserID:  <class 'uuid.UUID'> 6f6e526c-acd8-496f-88e0-6bfdd594e2c2
ObjectID:  <class 'int'> 6095016
ObjectClass:  <class 'str'> cottages
Views:  <class 'list'> [datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0)]
RecDate:  <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> 2021-07-13 15:50:32
Events:  <class 'list'> ['']
```

And a clickhouse table:

```
CREATE TABLE default.rec_eval_data
(
    `UserID` UUID,
    `ObjectID` Int32,
    `ObjectClass` String,
    `Views` Array(DateTime),
    `RecDate` DateTime,
    `Events` Array(String)
)
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree
ORDER BY (UserID, ObjectID)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

I'm trying different ways to insert the DF into the table, but i keep getting various errors.

I'm using clickhouse_driver library to perform stuff.

I have read [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422110/pandas-how-to-insert-dataframe-into-clickhouse) and used all the methods, but to no avail

What I have tried already:

1. Native:

   client.execute("INSERT INTO rec_eval_data VALUES", data.to_dict(orient='records'), types_check=True)

Error: clickhouse_driver.errors.TypeMismatchError: Code: 53. Type mismatch in VALUES section. Repeat query with types_check=True for detailed info. Column Views: argument out of range

2. Pandahouse:

   connection = dict(database='default', host='http://localhost:8123', user='default', schema='default', password='')

   ph.to_clickhouse(data, 'rec_eval_data', index=False, chunksize=100000, connection=connection)

Error: It uses http and GET method, which automatically acts in readonly mode, so I could not proceed. Maybe there's a way to change method to POST?

3. clickhouse_driver insert_dataframe:

   client.insert_dataframe('INSERT INTO rec_eval_data VALUES ', data)

Error: TypeError: Unsupported column type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. list or tuple is expected.

4. iteration:

   for date, row in data.T.iteritems():

   client.execute("INSERT INTO rec_eval_data "
   "(UserID, " 
   "ObjectID, " 
   "ObjectClass, " 
   "Views, " 
   "RecDate, " 
   "Events)" 
   " VALUES "
   "({UserID}, "
   "{ObjectID}, "
   "{ObjectClass}, "
   "{Views}, "
   "{RecDate}, "
   "{Events}) "
   .format(
   UserID=UserID,
   ObjectID=row['ObjectID'],
   ObjectClass=row['ObjectClass'],
   Views=row['UserID'],
   RecDate=row['RecDate'],
   Events=row['Events']))

Error: It tries to split UserID into pieces. Can't find how to avoid it: DB::Exception: Missing columns: '6bfdd594e2c2' '496f' 'acd8' '6f6e526c' while processing query: '(((`6f6e526c` - acd8) - `496f`) - 88.) - `6bfdd594e2c2`', required columns: '6f6e526c' 'acd8' '496f' '6bfdd594e2c2' '6f6e526c' 'acd8' '496f' '6bfdd594e2c2'.

Please, help, I can't fix it( I'm new both to CH and pandas(

Stack trace:

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- [clickhouse_driver](https://github.com/mymarilyn/clickhouse-driver) by *insert_dataframe*

! this code works only when for column *Events Array(String)* passed the empty array otherwise got the error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'" (it looks like it is the bug in *clickhouse_driver*).

```py
from datetime import datetime
from uuid import UUID
from clickhouse_driver import Client
import pandas as pd

client = Client(host='localhost', settings={'use_numpy': True})


def get_inserted_data():
    return [
            {
                'UserID': UUID('417ddc5d-e556-4d27-95dd-a34d84e40003'),
                'ObjectID': 1003,
                'ObjectClass': 'Class3',
                'Views': [datetime.now(), datetime.now()],
                'RecDate': datetime.now(),
                #'Events': ['aa', 'bb'] # got error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'"
                'Events': []
            }
        ]

data = []

for item in get_inserted_data():
    data.append([
        item['UserID'],
        item['ObjectID'],
        item['ObjectClass'],
        item['Views'],
        item['RecDate'],
        item['Events']
    ])

client.insert_dataframe(
    'INSERT INTO test.rec_eval_data VALUES',
    pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['UserID', 'ObjectID', 'ObjectClass', 'Views', 'RecDate', 'Events'])
)
```

- [clickhouse_driver](https://github.com/mymarilyn/clickhouse-driver) by *execute*

```py
from clickhouse_driver import Client
from iso8601 import iso8601

client = Client(host='localhost')

client.execute(
    'INSERT INTO test.rec_eval_data (UserID, ObjectID, ObjectClass, Views, RecDate, Events) VALUES',
    [{
        'UserID': '417ddc5d-e556-4d27-95dd-a34d84e40002',
        'ObjectID': 1002,
        'ObjectClass': 'Class2',
        'Views': [iso8601.parse_date('2021-08-02 01:00:00'), iso8601.parse_date('2021-08-03 01:00:00')],
        'RecDate': iso8601.parse_date('2021-08-02 01:00:00'),
        'Events': ['03', '04']
    }])
```

- [HTTP interface](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/http/)

```py
import requests

CH_USER = 'default'
CH_PASSWORD = ''
SSL_VERIFY = False

host = 'http://localhost:8123'
db = 'test'
table = 'rec_eval_data'

content = 'UserID\tObjectID\tObjectClass\tViews\tRecDate\tEvents' \
          '\n417ddc5d-e556-4d27-95dd-a34d84e46a50\t1001\tClass1\t[\'2021-08-01 00:00:00\',\'2021-08-02 00:00:00\']\t2021-08-01 00:00:00\t[\'01\',\'02\']'

content = content.encode('utf-8')
query_dict = {
    'query': 'INSERT INTO ' + db + '.' + table + ' FORMAT TabSeparatedWithNames '
}

r = requests.post(host, data=content, params=query_dict, auth=(CH_USER, CH_PASSWORD), verify=SSL_VERIFY)

print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Native
   client.execute('INSERT INTO rec_eval_data VALUES', data.to_dict('records'), settings={'max_partitions_per_insert_block':0})

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).